# How to filter and sort a text-block into an array, in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple text-block with 3 columns:

```
id_1    text_1  A
id_9    text_2  B
id_2    text_5  D
id_3    text_3  G
id_8    text_4  C
id_4    text_9  X
id_0    text_0  X
id_5    text_8  Z
...
```

and a PHP array:

```
$std_string = array ("A", "B", "X", "C", "M");
```

I want to filter and sort the text block into a new text-block, based on the order and existed text in`$std_string`.

Exactly, it will return a new text-block:

```
id_1
id_9
[DU]
id_8
[NO]
```

If the 3rd column (of orginal text-block) doesn't have a value in 1st column (which is listed in `$std_string`) (like **M**), it will return **[NO]**.

If the 3rd column (of orginal text-block) have two values in 1st column (like **X**), it will return **[DU]**.

Is there any suggestion to do it, in PHP?

---

> All data are **case-sensetive**.

Comment: it would be better if you edit the new and deserving posts. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
$text_block="id_1    text_1  A
id_9    text_2  B
id_2    text_5  D
id_3    text_3  G
id_8    text_4  C
id_4    text_9  X
id_0    text_0  X
id_5    text_8  Z";

$std_string = array ("A", "B", "X", "C", "M");

$rows = explode("\n", str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\t"," ",$text_block)));

$letter_ids = array();
foreach($std_string as $letter) {
    $letter_ids[$letter] = "[NO]";
}
for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++) {
    $cols = explode(" ",trim($rows[$i]));
    $letter = $cols[count($cols)-1];
    if(isset($letter_ids[$letter])) {
        if($letter_ids[$letter] == "[NO]") {
            $letter_ids[$letter] = $cols[0];
        } else {
            $letter_ids[$letter] = "[DU]";
        }
    }
}

$new_text_block = "";
foreach($letter_ids as $key => $val) {
    $new_text_block.= $val."\n";
}
echo "<pre>".$new_text_block."</pre>";
```

Output:

```
id_1
id_9
[DU]
id_8
[NO]
```

Comment: Why `$rows = explode("\n", str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\t"," ",$text_block)));` and not just `$rows = explode("\n", $text_block);`??

Comment: It's just because I don't know how the OP will insert his text block. It could contain tabs and windows newlines. In this way it's safe.